# is nServiceBus a proper fit to fufil this requirement?

Tags: soa, nservicebus

as a software engineer I want to tell your system when something needs to be done.  I want to provide the implementation code of what needs to be done.  I want your system to call into my code and execute my implementation.  I want my code to execute in its own processing space and probably on my own infrastructure and servers.  As a software engineer, I favor convention over configuration.

I need this feature because often times I work on service agreements for customers to deliver specialized, one off solutions, and I dont want to build this plumbing all of the time for each new client.

I simply want to write some code that does some work using my resources, and I want your system to begin the execution of my code.

Comment: What kind of code would it be?  Does the client system have to wait for a response or can it be done in the background?

Comment: the platform I am building needs to tell other systems when its time to do something.  these other systems, are typically C#, java, php, ruby, etc and are normally accessible over http.  the other systems also, need to tell my platform, when its time to do something, and my platform is http accessible.  i need to follow up with the customers but I beleive most message exchanges can be asyncronous.  i also beleive that some customers will want pub / sub message models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSB should be able to meet your needs.  You will be able to get messages from external systems that don't talk to an MS platform by exposing your endpoint(s) as WCF services(built-in).  NSB also supports Pub/Sub as well as many other message patterns.  As long as the exchanges can be unidirectional, you should be off to a good start.  NSB will handle all of the underlying plumbing you speak and will ensure that messages don't get lost.